# Which 3d software is right for me?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, workflow

I know this place is a Blender community but i wonder what is the best 3d software for me.
The reference of the my work I want is

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02k126v3Zu4 /
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NApVOHrbhqg /
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxBl73QX000 /

Will Blender fit my inclination?
I can use touchdesigner and after effect but never used a 3D program
And I want to make an image like an Amnesia scanner
Do you have any tutorials to recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, blender is the software you are looking for blender can do almost everything you imagine, also the big advantage of using blender is that you will get a million of tutorials about how to use it on YouTube , also it is open source so you will not even have to spend a coin on it, the only thing is you will have to be patient in order to create something as you want because there are many users who find it hard and leave it in the middle, so start from basic and one day you will achieve the results you want.